# how to sum identical values in array

Tags: python, numpy

How do I sum the second column values if the first column value is the same in an array?

e.g If I have an array `[0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,5],[2,6]`. The result should be `[0,1],[1,3],[2,11]`.

In my case I'm using a numpy array, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly? How do you get the result from what you've written?

Comment: Can we assume the first column is sorted? Or at least grouped in groups of the same (first-column) key value?

Comment: @smci Yes in this case you can assume the first column is sorted.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 1],
              [1, 1],
              [1, 2],
              [2, 5],
              [2, 6]])

d = {}
for k, v in a:
    d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + v

b = np.array(d.items())
```

returns

```
b = np.array([[ 0,  1],
              [ 1,  3],
              [ 2, 11]])
```

or a one-lines

```
from collections import Counter
b = np.array(sum((Counter({k:v}) for k,v in a), Counter()).items())
```

Comment: `Counter({k:v for k, v in a})` will return `[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 6)]`, it is not what is needed

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary because the first item actually is a key:

```
l=[ [0,1],[1,1],[1,2],[2,5],[2,6] ]
s={}
for e in l:
  if e[0] in s: s[e[0]] += e[1]
  else s[e[0]] = e[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one line solution without numpy (but using built-in itertools):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, imap
>>> arr = [[0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 5], [2, 6]]

>>> [[k, sum(imap(lambda x: x[1], g))] for (k, g) in groupby(sorted(arr), lambda x: x[0])]
[[0, 1], [1, 3], [2, 11]]
```

Comment: I like it. Very pythonic.

Comment: I don't like the idea of sorting data when it isn't really necessary; if speed matters, you should achieve the same goal in linear time.

Comment: @user2560053 the OP has confirmed you can assume the first column is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy smart indexing:

```
[[k,np.sum(x[x[:,0]==k][:,1])] for k in np.unique(x[:,0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can play all sorts of fun tricks to get a one liner (my favourite for sheer tenacity would be `Counter(chain.from_iterable([k] * v for k,v in myarray)).items()`), the most readable and likely most efficient way would be with a defaultdict and an explicit loop:

```
from itertools import defaultdict

count = defaultdict(int)
for k,v in myarray:
    count[k] += v

print(list(count.items()))
```